# Make Return[] do its proper (C++) task

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, return

I saw that there are many threads about the Return[] function on this site. There is even a very good description of its behavior. But what happens if I'm really new to Mathematica?

Without further ado, I want to use this function:

```
getBinIndex[eta_, pt_, etalimits_, ptlimits_] := 
     List[
       For[i = 1, i < Length[etalimits],     i++,
           If[eta < etalimits[[i + 1]], Return[i]]], 
       For[i = 1, i < Length[ptlimits], i++,
           If[pt < ptlimits[[i + 1]], Return[i]]]
         ];
```

As you can see, I am really new. I suppose there are 1 million ways of doing this in Mathematica but I have a C background and I feel the need to tell the computer everything. The function works. It returns a list with 2 variables which, after lots of testing, are OK. But it puts the results as the argument of two Return's: {Return[4],Return[5]} which I can't use as indexes for a...Table, for example. What do you need to do to get these Return[x] into x?

To give you an idea of how much a newb I am, I tried N[Return[i]].

Cheers,

Adrian

Comment: Given this a mathematica tag hoping that the question now makes sense. It has no relevance to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Catch[For[ ....   If[   Throw[i] ] ]
```

Of course in mathematica you hardly ever need loops..
something like

```
Position[etalimits,ei_/;ei<eta&][[1,1]]
```

will do.

edit .. try this:

```
   For[i = 1, i < Length[etalimits],     i++,
         If[eta < etalimits[[i + 1]], Return[i,CompoundExpression]]];,
```

Note the extra semicolon which makes the For[] loop a CompoundExpression. Personally I find this weird and wouldn't use it..

Comment: Thanks a lot george. It worked (the Catch version). I'm studying the Position version. This is peculiar, so my function's result is actually an exception :)). I have to study more about Mathematica.

Comment: @user2285967 You may find this thread useful: "[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/280)"

Comment: Thanks, Alexey! I actually bought THE Cookbook of Sal Mangano and Schaum's Outline of Mathematica. Now I have to make some time for them.